# Get table value using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, html-table, simple-html-dom

I'm writing this PHP to read the data from the following website, and the write it into database.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://backpack.tf/pricelist/spreadsheet');
$data = $html->find('.table tr td[1]');  
foreach($data as $result)
{
echo $result->plaintext . '<br />';
}
?>
```

I intended to get all the data in the tds and even the attribute inside the trs.
So, I tried by getting them in plain text first.
By far the code returns:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

How can I solve and improve the code?

Comment: How big is the spreadsheet? `file_get_html()` has a limit on the size of file it will process.

Comment: but why it isnt an object? it works for google(sorry if i am too noob)

Comment: It could be that the site you are requesting can't be requested through PHP (that is sometimes the case). Edit: it is returning the page

Comment: if it cant be requested through PHP, then is there any other method to achieve the same target?

Comment: If `file_get_html()` fails, it returns `false`, which isn't an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is working for your example.
It could be the memory limit for your executing script that's causing trouble.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','160M');
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://backpack.tf/pricelist/spreadsheet';

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);

$data = $html->find('.table tr td[1]');  
foreach($data as $result)
{
    echo $result->plaintext . '<br />';
}
```